# Effects of getting traffic tickets when drive in New York with an international driver license

Tags: driving

Several days ago, when I drove in New York State with a Canadian driver license, I got two tickets. One is for speeding (I drove at 84 mph at a 65 mph zone); the other is for not restraining my baby (16 month old) in the safety seat. I plan to get a US driver license soon. I was wondering whether those violations will induce the increase of auto insurance associated with my (future) US driver license. In addition, I would like to know what the approximate fine will be because the forms that I received from the police did not say the fine.

Thank you